# JSON Schema Validation Not working as expected for PropertyName

Tags: java, json

I am trying out json Schema validation Ref :https://wilddiary.com/validate-json-against-schema-in-java/

The data.json is below. The Validator checks and works for the value type based on the schema.

However If I try to change the propertyname id to say iddiff, the json is still is coming as valid, though I was expecting an Unrecognized field iddiff error. I dd try other libraries as well. Any pointers?

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
}
```

Comment: how does your schema look?

Comment: Using the same example as in https://wilddiary.com/validate-json-against-schema-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following link. This reference is easy and helpful.
http://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-json-schema-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Add to your schema: "additionalProperties": false

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Product",
  "description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "description": "The unique identifier for a product",
      "type": "integer"
    },
    ....
      "minItems": 1,
      "uniqueItems": true
    }
  },
  "required": ["id", "name", "price"],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

[Doc. for more information.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03#page-9)